# Meaning of first column of expanded children in perf report -g output

Tags: perf

I am looking at this output of `perf report -g`.

```
  Children      Self   Command  Shared Object       Symbol
-   87.46%      3.94%  my_cmd   libgomp.so.1.0.0    [.] omp_in_final                                                           
  + 83.53% omp_in_final                                                                                                     
  + 2.81% clone                                                                                                              
  + 1.12% _start
```

Based on the [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Overhead_calculation), my understanding is that the 3.94% and the 87.46% values shown mean that 3.94% of the samples taken occurred directly in the `omp_in_final` function, while 87.46% of the samples occurred either within the `omp_in_final` function or a function called by `omp_in_final`.

What isn't clear to me is what the 83.53% value above is indicating. Since the symbol associated with this value is also `omp_in_final`, I am not sure why that value is different from the 87.46% value above. Can anyone offer help about why these values are different?

Also, since the graph is in "caller" mode, I think this means that the output is indicating that `omp_in_final` is calling `clone` and `start_`. But, if this is the case, then what are the symbols that are shown underneath `omp_in_final` when I expand it? Are these functions that called `omp_in_final`?

```
-   87.46%     3.94%  my_cmd    libgomp.so.1.0.0    [.] omp_in_final                                                           
   - 83.53% omp_in_final                                                                                                      
        38.80% omp_get_num_procs                                                                                              
      + 21.33% do_manual_omp_version._omp_fn.0                                                                                
      + 3.61% do_bestcase_omp_version._omp_fn.0                                                                               
      + 3.39% do_omp_barrier_only._omp_fn.0

   .
   .
   .
```

I have looked at the `perf report` examples on the perf wiki, and I've come across some helpful examples (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742462/understanding-linux-perf-report-output)) that cover other cases. But I haven't yet seen a case like the one above - where the `omp_in_final` has a symbol under it that is also `omp_in_final` but with a different percentage next to it.

Answer (score 0):

After staring at this for a while, I think I might have gotten some insight into what the values mean.

Looking at this level (using different data, because I no longer have the perf.data file from the original run),

```
-   87.44%     3.69%  my_cmd    libgomp.so.1.0.0    [.] omp_in_final                                                           
   + 83.76% omp_in_final                                                                                                      
   + 2.71% clone                                                                                                              
   + 0.98% _start
```

I think the `clone` and `_start` lines are showing that, of the 3.69% of samples recorded within `omp_in_final`, 2.71% were reached in a stack trace from `clone` to `omp_in_final`, and 0.98% were reached in a stack trace from `_start` to `omp_in_final`.

This becomes evident upon expanding those subtrees.

```
-   87.44%     3.69%  my_cmd    libgomp.so.1.0.0    [.] omp_in_final                                                           
   + 83.76% omp_in_final                                                                                                      
   - 2.71% clone                                                                                                              
        start_thread                                                                                                          
        omp_in_final                                                                                                          
   - 0.98% _start                                                                                                             
        __libc_start_main                                                                                                     
      - main                                                                                                                  
         - 0.52% GOMP_parallel                                                                                                
              0.50% omp_in_final
```

From that, we can see that `clone` and `_start` both call functions that eventually lead to `omp_in_final`.

In contrast, the 83.76% associated with the `omp_in_final` subtree I believe is showing the stack traces *outside of* that 3.69% - that is, in functions *called by* `omp_in_final`. Together, the 83.76% and the 3.69% (=2.71%+0.98%) constitute all of the 87.44% spent within `omp_in_final` (both directly in the function itself and in functions called by it).

The subtree of `omp_in_final` in this case looks like this.

```
-   87.44%     3.69%  my_cmd    libgomp.so.1.0.0    [.] omp_in_final                                                           
   - 83.76% omp_in_final                                                                                                      
        37.82% omp_get_num_procs                                                                                              
      + 21.46% do_manual_omp_version._omp_fn.0                                                                                
      + 3.64% do_bestcase_omp_version._omp_fn.0                                                                               
      + 3.41% do_omp_barrier_only._omp_fn.0                                                                                   
        1.30% dynamic_omp_module4._omp_fn.1                                                                                   
        1.29% dynamic_omp_module4._omp_fn.2                                                                                   
        1.28% dynamic_omp_module1._omp_fn.0                                                                                   
        1.27% dynamic_omp_module3._omp_fn.0                                                                                   
        1.26% dynamic_omp_module2._omp_fn.1                                                                                   
        1.25% dynamic_omp_module4._omp_fn.0                                                                                   
        1.25% dynamic_omp_module2._omp_fn.0                                                                                   
        1.24% dynamic_omp_module4._omp_fn.3                                                                                   
        1.24% dynamic_omp_module3._omp_fn.2                                                                                   
        1.23% dynamic_omp_module3._omp_fn.1
```

To me, it is a little confusing at first how the output shows the 83.76%, 2.71%, the 0.98% all with the same alignment and formatting, as if these numbers have the same meaning. But, as I read it, I think the subtrees under the 2.71% and 0.98% values are showing stack traces *leading up to* `omp_in_final`, whereas the 83.76% subtree is showing the stack traces that *start at* `omp_in_final`.